# xx is not a valid win32 application

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, win32-process

I developed a Win32 program using VC++ 2012 (Express 2012 for Windows Desktop). I chose "Win32" / "Win32 Console Application" while setting up my project. I can run it at Win-7, but failed at POSReady 2009, which is close to WinXP. While I ran it under POSReady 2009, it shows as title.
Is there any way to configure project property on VC++2012 or any other ways to conquer it? Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851139.aspx

Comment: I followed the direction of that page as below, installing Visual Studio 2012 Update 4, then re-built it. The result is the same.

You must install Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 to add support for Windows XP and Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Did you actually change the General + Platform Toolset setting in your project?  You must pick v110_xp there to get a compatible build.  No idea if Express actually supports this btw.  Kinda doubtful, there's nothing very "express" about getting the entire v7.1 Windows SDK installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install VS 2012 Update 1 or later or VS 2013 Express, and set your Platform Toolset to "v110_xp" or "v120_xp" to make an application that is compatible with Windows XP Service Pack 3 / Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2).

The key difference between the "v110"/"v120" and "v110_xp"/"v120_xp" Platform Toolset is the Windows SDK. "v110"/"v120" builds with the Windows 8.x SDK which supports targeting Windows Vista or later. It is not possible to build a Windows XP compatible application using the Windows 8.x SDK. Therefore, to target Windows XP / Windows Server 2003 you have to use the alternative Platform Toolset which uses the Windows SDK 7.1A which is included with Express for Windows Desktop.

With either Windows SDK, be sure to set _WIN32_WINNT appropriately for the OSes you are targeting. See [Using the Windows Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx). For Windows XP / Windows Server 2003 set it to _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501

Note that for DirectX development, this has some important impacts because the Windows 7.1 SDK was before the DirectX SDK integration that was done for the Windows 8.x SDK. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/26/visual-studio-2012-update-1.aspx) blog post for more details.

Comment: It works. I set the Platform Toolset as "v110_xp" and built it, then the program can run at WinXP & POSReady 2009.
The extra description for WIN32_WINNT and DirectX teaches me a lot too.
I appreciate this answer very much. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The "v110_xp" platform toolset ends up using the Windows 7.1A SDK which defaults _WIN32_WINNT to 0x601 which works on Windows 7, but won't work on Windows Vista or Windows XP unless you explicitly set it to something else. The only reason to change the Platform Toolset is to target Windows XP. You should set _WIN32_WINNT either way.